# Data collection form inputs hidden Struts 2

Tags: struts2, hidden-field, data-collection

My problem happens when I send data from hidden fields to action. No data collected properly and the result page I receive the following message:

- Error setting expression 'idplatos' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@354c0a31'
- Error setting expression 'idrestaurantes' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@4786b9ce'

In this form the value of hidden fields come from a previous query, on the same page that query other data that are not in the form is displayed correctly.This the code for form:

```
<s:form action="Detalles.action" namespace="/" method="POST">
        <s:hidden name="idplatos" value="idplatos"/>
        <s:hidden name="idrestaurantes" value="restaurante.idrestaurante"/>
        <s:submit key="detalles" align="center"/>
</s:form>
```

This is the code from action:

```
public class PlatoAction extends ActionSupport {

private ArrayList <Platos> detalles;
private int idplatos;
private int idrestaurantes;

public String execute() throws Exception {

    Platos plato = new Platos();
    Restaurantes restaurante = new Restaurantes();

    plato.setIdplatos(getIdplatos());
    restaurante.setIdrestaurantes(getIdrestaurantes());

    System.out.println("idpla");
    System.out.println("idpres");

InterfacePlatosDAO PlatosDAO = FactoriaDAO.getPlatosDAO("MySQL");
detalles = PlatosDAO.detallePlato(plato, restaurante);

return SUCCESS;
}

public ArrayList<Platos> getDetalles() {
    return detalles;
}

public void setDetalles(ArrayList<Platos> detalles) {
    this.detalles = detalles;
}

public int getIdplatos() {
    return idplatos;
}

public void setIdplatos(int idplatos) {
    this.idplatos = idplatos;
}

public int getIdrestaurantes() {
    return idrestaurantes;
}

public void setIdrestaurantes(int idrestaurantes) {
    this.idrestaurantes = idrestaurantes;
}
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Check what values are being submitted.

Comment: the problem is that I do not take the value of these two fields in the form have to then move to a new query and shows me the page of results in the following error: 
Error setting expression 'idplatos' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@354c0a31'
Error setting expression 'idrestaurantes' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@4786b9ce'
It's as if I did not recognize that value.

Comment: The action can not be performed because the new query collects data from the form fields well. 
Sorry for my English ... it's depressing ....

Comment: Inspect your form in the browser before submitting.

Comment: I just checked on the form that the value of the fields I do not collect. But if I take it out of the form and put it into a property correctly shows me what its value ...... why?

Comment: Already solved, the problem was that, for the form of the iterator value pick was necessary to place: 
value = "% {restaurante.idrestaurante}" 
Thank you very much for the help

Comment: You can put your solution as an answer to help future visitors with this problem.